# 'str' object has no attribute 'makefile'

Tags: python, django

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\Rochak.virtualenvs\GFG\GFG\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner 
  response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Rochak.virtualenvs\GFG\GFG\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Rochak.virtualenvs\GFG\GFG\Scripts\authentication\views.py", line 7, in home
  return HTTPResponse("Hello Rochak!")
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 256, in init
  self.fp = sock.makefile("rb")

Exception Type: AttributeError at /authentication/hello/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'makefile'
```

Comment: You posted your entire traceback, that's great, but please post your code as well

Answer (score 15):

You're returning a `http.client.HTTPResponse`.

You need to return a `django.http.HttpResponse`.

Fix your import.

Comment: It's spelled a little differently.  I believe the class name is `HttpResponse`

Comment: Thanks alot!! I have been in trouble for a long moment just because of multiple imports!

Comment: @JohnGordon Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 8):

There's a little mistake. Change the line:

> ```
> return HTTPResponse("Hello Rochak!")
> ```

with

```
return HttpResponse("Hello Rochak!")
```

And include this line to the top part as well:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
```

Note: note that `HTTPResponse` will be `HttpResponse`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
   #Remove http.client.HTTPResponse from import and follow:
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from django.http import HttpResponse

   # Create your views here.
   def home(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello bro")
```

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the capital of "TTP" in the return response - HTTPResponse but the correct one is the small letter of ttp like this:HttpResponse

Answer (score 1):

Import the `HttpResponse` class from `django.http.response` module

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
    
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rendering string content")
```

Note: In some editors, when you add `HttpResponse` without importing it from the `Django`, it automatically imports the similarly named module from `http.client (from http.client import HTTPResponse)`

Answer (score 1):

step: go to views.py change line with add this line.

change line: `from http.client import HTTPResponse` 
add this Line: `from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse`